# Unable to compile - PJSIP - VOIP application

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, voip, pjsip

I am trying to create a sample voip app using the below url.

http://code.google.com/p/pjsip-iphone-audio-driver/wiki/HowToCompile

I am following the steps mentioned in the above URL. When I am trying to execute the below command on terminal I am getting the below error.

```
pjsip eit$ cd ~/Desktop/pjsip
Rs-Mac-mini-2:pjsip eit$ chmod 755 compile.sh
Rs-Mac-mini-2:pjsip eit$ ./compile.sh
./compile.sh: line 15: autoconf: command not found
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin ~/Desktop/pjsip
~/Desktop/pjsip
./compile.sh: line 51: make: command not found
./compile.sh: line 52: make: command not found
```

What is the issue here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [Apple's "Xcode" page here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), sign in and then click on the "View Downloads" link for additional developer tools.

The thing you need to install are the "Command Line Tools" for Xcode.

You can also install these tools by going to the "Downloads" tab within Xcode's preferences, which is elaborated on [in this FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/).

Once you do that you, you should be able to do "configure" and "make".